# Why does sed command contain at symbols

Tags: sed

I don't understand why the following sed command contains an @ symbol:

```
sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd
```

I've looked at /etc/pam.d/sshd for the before/after effects of this command:

BEFORE:

```
...
# Set the loginuid process attribute.
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
...
```

AFTER:

```
...
# Set the loginuid process attribute.
session optional pam_loginuid.so
....
```

Is the @ symbol possibly part of regex or sed syntax?
Could not find any doco on this.

Note: The above sed command is actually part of a Dockerfile RUN command in tutorial:
https://docs.docker.com/examples/running_ssh_service/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What delimiters can you use in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914360/what-delimiters-can-you-use-in-sed)

Answer (score 10):

These are alternate delimiters for the regular expressions and replacement string.  Handy when your regex or replacement string includes '/'.

Comment: It should also be noted that this isn't a `sed` specific convention, but is also supported by Perl and other languages that let you specify the regex delimiter.

Answer (score 6):

From the [sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command)

> The syntax of the s (as in substitute) command is ‘s/regexp/replacement/flags’. The / characters may be uniformly replaced by any other single character within any given s command. The / character (or whatever other character is used in its stead) can appear in the regexp or replacement only if it is preceded by a \ character.

From the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html):

> [2addr]s/BRE/replacement/flags
>
> Substitute the replacement string for instances of the BRE in the pattern space. Any character other than <backslash> or <newline> can be used instead of a  to delimit the BRE and the replacement. Within the BRE and the replacement, the BRE delimiter itself can be used as a literal character if it is preceded by a <backslash>.

Answer (score 3):

as other says, it is another delimiter than traditionnal `/` in the `s///`action. This is usually used when `/` is found/part of the pattern like searching (or replacing by) a unix path that need to escape the `/`

```
s/\/my\/path/\/Your\/path/
# same as
s@my/path@/Your/path@
```

You often use a character that is not alpha numeric (but you can). The only (logical) constraint is to avoid a special character  (aka special meaning like `^$[]{}()+\*.`) for regex that make it difficult to read (but functionnal) and without the feature of this character in the pattern

```
echo "b(a)l" | sed 's(.)()('
```