# What delimiters can you use in sed?

Tags: sed, gnu, delimiter

We normally see people complaining about the `unknown option to s'` error in `sed` when they want to use a pattern that contains the `sed` delimiter.

For example, if we are using `/`:

```
$ var="hel/lo"
$ sed "s/a/$var/g" <<< "haha"
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown option to `s'
```

So we advise to use another delimiter, for example `|`:

```
$ sed "s|a|$var|g" <<< "haha"
hhel/lohhel/lo
```

However, I want to know what are the possible delimiters `sed` can accept... since it seems to be almost any character including regex-like ones (`*`, `?`, `.`, ...)!

In my `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`:

```
$ sed 's/a/b/g' <<< "haha"
hbhb
$ sed 's_a_b_g' <<< "haha"
hbhb
$ sed 's#a#b#g' <<< "haha"
hbhb
$ sed 's$a$b$g' <<< "haha"
hbhb
$ sed 's?a?b?g' <<< "haha"
hbhb
$ sed 's*a*b*g' <<< "haha"
hbhb
$ sed 's-a-b-g' <<< "haha"
hbhb
$ sed 's.a.b.g' <<< "haha"
hbhb
$ sed 'sXaXbXg' <<< "haha"
hbhb
$ sed 'sxaxbxg' <<< "haha"
hbhb
$ sed 's1a1b1g' <<< "haha"
hbhb
```

Even `a` works here if it is escaped:

```
$ sed 'saaabag' <<< "haha"
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unknown option to `s'
$ sed 'sa\aabag' <<< "haha"
hbhb
```

Is there any specification for this?