# Remove a href link text from a file

Tags: sed

I have few thousand files with a href tag as follows:

```
href="../../../../file/old.html
```

I am trying to remove this from all the files.
I have tried sed but it throws an error and fails.

```
sed -i '/href="../../../../file/old.html"/c\' *.html 
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown command: `.'
```

Suggestions please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression is not entirely correct. You need to say `sed 's/pattern/replacement/g' file`. Or, using another delimiter if `/` is in the pattern and you don't want to escape it, `sed 's#pattern#replacement#g' file` ([or any other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33914360/1983854)).

Also, the usage of `\` may mislead `sed`, since it escapes the character after it. If you want a literal one, you have to escape it.

So you need to say something like:

```
sed 's#href="../../../../file/old.html"#c\\#g' file
#                                         ^
#            double \ so that you have a literal \
```

Let's test it:

```
$ cat a
hello <a href="../../../../file/old.html">bye</a>
hehehe
$ sed 's#href="../../../../file/old.html"#c\\#g' a
hello <a c\>bye</a>
hehehe
```

Comment: Spoke too soon. It didn't change. I had opened the html file in an editor, but it did say there's been a change and ask for a reload..

Comment: sed -i 's#href="../../../../file/old.html"##g' - This worked all file.!