# Unix command for replacing strings which have "/"

Tags: unix, sed, grep

I know that for replacing a string (in a file which has `matchstring` string), we can use following command 
 
`grep -rl matchstring somedir/ | xargs sed -i 's/string1/string2/g'`
 
 
How can I use/change the command if my string has special characters like "/"? 
For example: 
string1: "/home/folder1" 
string2: "/home/folder1/folder2"

Comment: You can use (almost) any delimiter character, for example 's,string1,string2,g'. [What delimiters can you use in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914360/what-delimiters-can-you-use-in-sed)

Comment: @jamieguinan, I did not know that. It worked! Thanks a lot.

Comment: also note that filenames having characters like space can cause issue.. use `grep -rlZ 'matchstring' somedir/ | xargs -0 `

Answer (score 0):

As @jamieguinan mentioned in his command, almost any delimiter character can be used. So, I changed the command as following: 
 `grep -rl matchstring somedir/ | xargs sed -i 's,string1,string2,g'` 
 Where string1 and string2 are: /home/folder1 and /home/folder1/folder2, respectively.