# replace variable on file with sed -i

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I try to replace variable in a file but the variable is not replaced after the execution of the script. i just see that my file was modified with the date when i run the script.

Here my script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
###################################################################
#
# NOM   : CONFIG_PROFIL
#     
###################################################################

##--------variable---------->>
DEST_DIR="profil"
chemin_env="/ords/test/profilprd"



sed -i 's/^$env/${chemin_env}/' $DEST_DIR/index_prive.htm


echo -*-*- Traitement terminé  -*-*
```

Here my file with the variable that i want to replace :

```
<frame name="mainFrame" src="$env/PG_LOGIN.pLogin?msg=" marginwidth="5" >
```

What i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: you should put escape char before dollar sign (which is in front of env ) Modify as below :  sed -i 's/\$env/${chemin_env}/' $DEST_DIR/index_prive.htm

Comment: many thanks it's working but now in my file i get ${chemin_env} and not the content of the variable @RaviKulkarni

Comment: `sed -i "s,^$env,${chemin_env}," $DEST_DIR/index_prive.htm`

Comment: ok. you just need double quotes instead of single quotes in sed statement so script understand its varaible and needs to replaced with its vale :  sed -i "s/\$env/${chemin_env}/" $DEST_DIR/index_prive.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Till what I understand your question, you should use `sed` like:

```
sed -i "s~\$env~${chemin_env}~" $DEST_DIR/index_prive.htm
```

In your question:

```
's/^$env/${chemin_env}/'
```

1) You have used single quotes which prevent any substitution. So value of `${chemin_env}` won't get substituted.

2) Also `^` means beginning of the string and in your file `$env` is not in beginning of the string.

3) To prevent value of `$env` from getting substituted, you need to use it like `\$env`.

4) After making the above 3 corrections if the value of `${chemin_env}` get substituted, it won't work because the variable contains `/` which you are using as delimeter in your `sed` expression. That's why I used `~` as delimeter instead. [What delimiters can you use in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914360/what-delimiters-can-you-use-in-sed)

Comment: thanks for your answer but it's doesn't change ${chemin_env} in index_prive.htm with "s~\$env~${chemin_env}~"

Comment: @MathieuMourareau, please correct me if I am wrong. You want to change the string `$env` to the value of `${chemin_env}` ? Because assuming that's the case, I have tried the same on my machine.

Comment: i'm sorry that's works :)