# How to Disable special character functionality in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

i want to replace special string using sed but how to disable special characeter functionality.

`%D/%M/%Y %H:%I:%S,%F000` want to replace with `%d/%m/%y %H:%i:%s,%f000`

```
sed -i '/s\b%D/%M/%Y %H:%I:%S,%F000\b/%d/%m/%y %H:%i:%s,%f000/g' inputfile.txt
```

Comment: Which "special character" is the problem?

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unknown command: `%'

Answer (score 1):

I found 2 issues in your `sed` command:

1. You have placed `s` after delimiter (`/`). The search command `s` should be before delimiter.
2. Your search pattern contains forward slash and you have used the
   same as your delimiter which will create issues. `sed` can use
   variety of delimiters apart from widely used forward slash. Refer -
   [what-delimiters-can-you-use-in-sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914360/what-delimiters-can-you-use-in-sed)

After fixing both, here is the updated `sed` command (i have used `!` as delimiter):

```
sed -i 's!%D/%M/%Y %H:%I:%S,%F000!%d/%m/%y %H:%i:%s,%f000!g' inputfile.txt
```