# How to add string contain / character to a file in shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have a string in my .sh file

```
  Path="etc/name"
```

This I need to write into a file.

This is my File.txt

```
 Name:Tom

 My_Path:add path here 

 Address:Xyz
```

Here in this file I need to replace path by the  'path' variable in shell script.

I used

```
   sed -i -e "s/\(My_Path=\).*/\1$path/" file.txt
```

But getting error like :

```
   Sed: -e expression #1, unknown option to s
```

my desired output is , the file My_Path.txt should contain

```
 Name:Tom

 My_Path:"etc/name" 

 Address:Xyz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your `Path` variable also has `/` (forward-slash) which gets interpreted as delimiter of your `sed`.

So try using some other delimiter. Here i am using `|` as delimiter:

```
sed -i -e "s|\(My_Path:\).*|\1$Path|" file.txt
```

Also refer: [what-delimiters-can-you-use-in-sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914360/what-delimiters-can-you-use-in-sed)

Comment: By using | delimiter if worked fine

Comment: @Aravind: If satisified with the answer, please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First escape slashes on your variable

```
path=$(echo $path | sed "s/\//\\\\\//g")
```

Then use this sed line

```
sed -i "s/My_Path:.*$/My_Path:$path/" file.txt
```