# what does the @ sign mean in the sed -e 's@ *@ @g' command in a makefile?

Tags: sed

I met a makefile as shown below:

```
GENERAL_RULES   = $(WM_DIR)/rules/General
include $(GENERAL_RULES)/general


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Declare names of make system control files derived from file 'files'
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

OBJECTS_DIR     = $(MAKE_DIR)/$(WM_OPTIONS)
OPTIONS         = $(OBJECTS_DIR)/options
FILES           = $(OBJECTS_DIR)/files
VARS            = $(OBJECTS_DIR)/variables
SFILES          = $(OBJECTS_DIR)/sourceFiles

-include $(OPTIONS)


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Declare dependency of all make system files on FILES
# Causes all derived files to be remade if any are changed or missing
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

all : $(OPTIONS) $(SFILES) $(VARS)

$(OPTIONS) : $(MAKE_DIR)/options
    @$(CPP) $(GFLAGS) $(MAKE_DIR)/options | sed -e 's@   *@ @g' > $(OPTIONS)
```

Can anyone explain the meaning of the last line of code above? There are three @ signs in one single sed command. I didn't quite understand the meaning of the @ sign. Please help.

Comment: Please identify in your makefile those whitespaces which are tabs and thereby allow to tell them apart from those whitespaces which are merely spaces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does sed command contain at symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161275/why-does-sed-command-contain-at-symbols)

Comment: @Yunnosch  You mean the whitespaces after the first @ sign is a tab, and the whitespace after the second @ sign is mere space? What does those @ signs mean?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Could you double check the first whitespace? In my experiments the result is weird if there is only one whitespace. It makes more sense if there are two, e.g. two tabs, or two blanks, or maybe a blank and a tab, or a tab and a blank...

Answer (score 1):

Sed is quite tolerant when it comes to setting up a search and replace, allowing for many characters to serve as delimiter.

The

```
sed -e 's@   *@ @g'
```

is probably more easily recognisable as

```
sed -e 's/   */ /g'
```

i.e.

- search and replace
- the kind of white space seen before the first delimiter, i.e. a tab
- any number, including 0 (which makes me think that there must be two tabs before the second delimiter, one "always", second "repetition any number")
- with the whitespace after the second delimiter, i.e.  a single blank/space
- globally